# Как остановить цикл? C#

Tags: c#

Есть кнопка которая при нажатии запускает действие, и при повторном нажатии останавливает

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var DoWork = new Work();
        if (Button.Text == "Начать")
        {
            Button.Text = "Стоп";
            DoWork.SomeWork();
        }
        else
        {
            followButton.Text = "Начать";
            DoWork.Stop(true);
        }
    }
```

Есть метод который выполняет работу в цикле и при повторном нажатии нужно его остановить:

```
class Work
{
    private bool _stopWork = false;

    public void Stop(bool stopWork)
    {
        _stopWork = stopWork;
    }

    public void SomeWork()
    {
       Цикл
       if (_stopWork)
           break;
    }
}
```

Но это не работает, в режиме дебага смотрел, при нажатии кнопки выполняется метод public void Stop(bool stopWork), но в методе SomeWork() _stopWork все ровно ровняется false. Почему так? Как это исправить?

Comment: Интересно, а как у вас такой цикл работает без заморозки интерфейса...

Comment: цикл не бесконечный, в нём есть долгие действия который выполняются в асинхронном режиме

Comment: мне кажется я не правильно реализую ООП, до этого когда всё в классе формы было работало нормально

Comment: var DoWork = new Work(); при клике вы каждый раз создаете инстанс этого класса и стоп срабатывает у свежесозданного, а не у того, у кого был запущен SomeWork()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуй, вынесу комментарий [vitidev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191496/vitidev) в ответ. У Вас действительно при каждом клике создаётся новый объект класса `Work`. И работа запускается или останавливается каждый раз в другом экземпляре класса. Чтобы этого избежать, необходимо объявление `var DoWork = new Work();` вынести за пределы обработчиков нажатий и сделать `DoWork`, например, свойством класса. Тогда каждый раз обращение будет идти к одному и тому же объекту.

И ещё добавление по правильности ООП лично от меня: не стоит передавать в метод `Stop()` булев аргумент. Название метода чётко говорит о том, что он должен остановить работу. Однако, если передать в него `false`, метод перестанет выполнять своё предназначение, что не есть хорошо.

Принимая во внимание оба замечания, ваш код можно переписать так:

```cs
private Work DoWork = new Work(); // Инициализация таким образом не является хорошей идеей и стоит здесь только для примера. По-хорошему инициализировать свойство следует в конструкторе.

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button.Text == "Начать")
        {
            Button.Text = "Стоп";
            DoWork.SomeWork();
        }
        else
        {
            followButton.Text = "Начать";
            DoWork.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Класс будет выглядеть так:

```cs
class Work
{
    private bool _stopWork = false;

    public void Stop()
    {
        _stopWork = true;
    }

    public void SomeWork()
    {
       _stopWork = false; // Чтобы можно было начать цикл при новом клике
       Цикл
       if (_stopWork)
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил этого